# Downloaded map not visible in hybrid or satellite mode and visible only in normal mode for offline. Here Maps SDK

Tags: ios, swift, maps, offline, here-api

I have downloaded maps using here sdk in iOS and nmamaploader. I am able to see the map in only normal mode for offline state. any other states such as hybrid or satellite mode shows only blank nmamapview. Is there anything to add while downloading map or so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hybrid and Satellite modes are available only in online state.

Comment: Is there any possibility to add satellite mode in offline state in near future?